# Issue Creating New Project Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using eclipse for the first time in a few weeks and when I try to create a new project it is being marked as a `test` and gives me an error when I create a main method.  [image]

I have been using eclipse for a while and this error happened once previously.  I solved it by messing around with a bunch of settings in properties/preferences and reinstalling eclipse but I would really appreciate help finding an easier way to fix this.

Here is the main method that I have.  I am not really concerned about the error with the main method, more so with why the projects have `[test]` when I create them.
[image]

Not sure if this helps, but when I go to create a project this is the first instance of the `[test]`[image]

Comment: Well... Is there a compilation error in the code ?

Comment: Before I can compile it there is an error and the yellow box says `This method has a constructor name` and `change to constructor`, even before I have a main method it says `[test]`.  Why is that happening

Comment: This red x probably indicates that the file does not compile, eclipse has built-in compiler which will directly redify your errors while writing code. Post your code.

Comment: Post the relevant code

Comment: Method with the name the same as class name is considered as constructor. But in this particular example my eclipse just show only a warning. Generally: in java name class with Capital letter.

Comment: Thank you that takes away the error but can you help me with fixing the `[test]` thing when I create projects? @krzydyn

Comment: The thing in square brackets is related to version control (like git or svn)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that, can you explain? @krzydyn

Comment: I guess it is not important for your code. Just informs about some metadata (like I said - source version control)

Comment: So how do I revert it back to a previous version like my other projects? @krzydyn

Comment: It's hard to tell what puts that `[test]` label without knowing what plugins you have installed. Could be JUnit, CVS etc. If you download a standard eclipse package and create a project it won't show it.

Comment: try to refresh eclipse with last updates